# Collapse together pandas row that respect a list of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, sentence

So, i have a dataframe of the type:

| Doc | String |
| --- | --- |
| A | abc |
| A | def |
| A | ghi |
| B | jkl |
| B | mnop |
| B | qrst |
| B | uv |

What I'm trying to do is to merge/collpase rows according to a two conditions:

- they must be from the same document
- they should be merged together up to a max length

I have

So that, for example if I will get max_len == 6:

| Doc | String |
| --- | --- |
| A | abcdef |
| A | defghi |
| B | jkl |
| B | mnop |
| B | qrstuv |

he output doesn't have to be that strict. To explain the why: i have a document and i was able to split it into sentences, I'd like to have it now in a dataframe with each "new sentence" being of maximal length.

Comment: I don't understant this row `A  defghi` in the expected output: Wasn't `def` already used in the first row - or have I misunderstood the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a *pure* Pandas solution (i.e. do the grouping only by using Pandas methods). You could try the following though:

```py
def group(col, max_len=6):
    groups = []
    group = acc = 0
    for length in col.values:
        acc += length
        if max_len < acc:
            group, acc = group + 1, length
        groups.append(group)
    return groups

groups = df["String"].str.len().groupby(df["Doc"]).transform(group)
res = df.groupby(["Doc", groups], as_index=False).agg("".join)
```

The `group` function takes a column of string lengths for a `Doc` group and builds `groups` that meet the `max_len` condition. Based on that another `groupby` over `Doc` and `groups` then aggregates the strings.

Result for the sample:

```
  Doc  String
0   A  abcdef
1   A     ghi
2   B     jkl
3   B    mnop
4   B  qrstuv
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried to run this code so there might be bugs, but essentially:

`uniques = list(set(df['Doc'].values))`

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=uniques, columns=df.columns)`

`for doc in uniques:`

`x_df = df.loc[df['Doc']==doc, 'String']`

`concatenated = sum(x_df['String'].values)[:max_length]`

`new_df.loc[doc, 'String'] = concatenated`